# how to let logical and operator (&) treat the NaN value depends on the other side's value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

in pandas or numpy's I want something like following: True & NaN == True, False & False == Fase, NaN & NaN == NaN

What is the most efficient way to do this? so far I have to do it as:

```
(a.fillna(True) & b.fillna(True)).where(~(a.isna() & b.isna()), None)
```

example:

```
from itertools import product
a = pd.DataFrame((product([True, False, None], [True, False, None])))
display(a)
display((a[0].fillna(True) & a[1].fillna(True)).where(~(a[0].isna() & a[1].isna()), None))
```

out put is:

```
    0   1
0   True    True
1   True    False
2   True    None
3   False   True
4   False   False
5   False   None
6   None    True
7   None    False
8   None    None

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8     None
dtype: object
```

I have 2 cases: A. most row has NaN and B. only a few row has NaN
I wonder what is the best way to do this in these 2 cases respectively

**performance**

```
b = a.sample(int(1e5), weights=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.01], ignore_index=True, replace=True)
c = a.sample(int(1e5), weights=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,80], ignore_index=True, replace=True)
display(b.isna().all(axis="columns").sum())
# 117 full NaN row
display(c.isna().all(axis="columns").sum())
# 90879 full NaN rows

import timeit
timeit.timeit(lambda: b.all(1).mask(b.isna().all(1)), number=100)
# 2.4s
timeit.timeit(lambda: c.all(1).mask(c.isna().all(1)), number=100)
# 1.6s
timeit.timeit(lambda: b.stack().groupby(level=0).all().reindex(b.index), number=100)
#3.3s
timeit.timeit(lambda: c.stack().groupby(level=0).all().reindex(c.index), number=100)
#0.9s
```

So yes as expected, the stack method, first drop all nan before compute, thus it is way faster for most NaN situation.

Comment: `True & NaN` cannot be `True`. You do not know what `Nan` is. thus the correct result of `True&Nan` is `Nan`, while `False&Nan` is `False`. on the other hand, `True | Nan` is `True` while `False | Nan` is `Nan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mask`:

```
df.all(1).mask(df.isna().all(1))

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8      NaN
dtype: object
```

another way is to use `stack`:

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).all().reindex(df.index)

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8      NaN
dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks! the mask one essentially what I did I think, but you extended to multiple columns, nice. but can you explain what the stack one is doing here?

Comment: I can explain a bit for the mask. default all(skipna
=True) Exclude NA/null values. If the entire row/column is NA and skipna is True, then the result will be True. So basically the all behave the exact we I wanted, except the all NaN situation. Then the mask is used to put NaN for all NaN situation. very cute.

Comment: ok, I get it the stack method, actually have similar idea. the stack(dropna=True) will drop all the NaN value. Then the groupby group them into row pairs without NaN for example in my row-2 it only have True in side the group, then we do a all() to get it. The tricky bit is groupby(level=0).all() remember all none-full-nan row's index. thus when we reindex with the original one the missing rows will be NaN. Also cute. I fell, first one will be faster when only a little bit full NaN row. 2nd one should be faster when almost all row are full NaN.